# Absolute div position - make it stick to the right

Tags: css, html, css-position

I set some absolute div position like this:

```
left: 700px;
```

But when I resize browser my div doesn't move, of course. How can I set it's position to be floated right and move left, when resizing window?

To show the situation, look at [this site](http://photo.vamsite.ru/#).
Look at image slider and arrow to the right of it. It's style:

```
#slides .next,#slides .prev {
    top:165px;
    left:-20px;
    width:24px;
    height:43px;
    display:block;
    z-index:999;

    position: absolute;
}

#slides .next {
    left: 700px;
}
```

And now try to resize window with that slider. My arrow will stay at the same position but it should move left with slider background.

Nothing related to: `float: right; right: 0px;` etc don't work.

Comment: Aaarrrrgggh music playing when I open that link...

Comment: @peehaa sorry, that's not my site :(

Comment: Nevermind. Just forgot to change the volume from music production to normal :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Remove `left: -20px;` from `#slides .next, #slides .prev` (you can move it to `.prev`)
- Remove `left: 700px;` from `.next`
- Add `right: 0` to `.next`.

And voilá, your `.next` will always adjust itself to the right of `#slides` (which has `position: relative`).

Answer (score 1):

Could you use "right:###px" to position the element instead of left? If you need it to be positioned absolutely based off the right side of your content rather than the right side of the window, wrap it in a container:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:900px; height:90px; margin:10px auto;">
    <p>Some arbitrary content.</p>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px;">Absolutely positioned left content</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px;">Absolutely positioned right content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No idea how you noticed that colon on a 2 year old post :)